# Only one row is affected for the updating of quantity PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I met with some error with the shopping cart.
it basically, only able to update the first row in the shopping cart and not the rest.
Below are an example of what I'm trying to do.
Example;
when I buy product A, it will be in the cart,
when I buy product A again, it will be updated as qty 2, not inserted as another row.

When I was doing the code,
the code works only for the first row, not the rest of the role.
Meaning,
When I buy product A and add product A again in the cart, the qty will be updated to 2.
HOWEVER, when I buy another product,such as Product B, and add Product B again,
the qty will not be updated,
instead, it will be inserted as new row.

Below is my code,
can someone help me with the part?
Thank you

```
<?php
if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {
function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue = "") 
{
  if (PHP_VERSION < 6) {
    $theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;
  }

  $theValue = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string") ? mysql_real_escape_string($theValue) : mysql_escape_string($theValue);

  switch ($theType) {
    case "text":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;    
    case "long":
    case "int":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "double":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? doubleval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "date":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;
    case "defined":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
      break;
  }
  return $theValue;
}
}

$editFormAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
  $editFormAction .= "?" . htmlentities($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
}


if ((isset($_POST["MM_insert"])) && ($_POST["MM_insert"] == "form1")) {
$selectProduct = "SELECT * FROM supermarketcart;";  
$qrySeledtedProduct = mysql_query($selectProduct);
$fetchSelectedProduct = mysql_fetch_assoc($qrySeledtedProduct); 


if($fetchSelectedProduct['sid']!= $_POST['id']) {


  $insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO supermarketcart (sid, pname, pdescription, package, pprice, pimage, username) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)",
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['id'], "int"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['name'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['description'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['package'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['price'], "double"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['imagename'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['username'], "text"));

  mysql_select_db($database_MyDatabase, $MyDatabase);
  $Result1 = mysql_query($insertSQL, $MyDatabase) or die(mysql_error());

  $insertGoTo = "cart.php";
  if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
    $insertGoTo .= (strpos($insertGoTo, '?')) ? "&" : "?";
    $insertGoTo .= $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
  }
  header(sprintf("Location: %s", $insertGoTo));

  }

  {
      $insertGoTo = "cart.php";
      $updateqtyAmt = $fetchSelectedProduct['qty'] +1;
      $updateQty = "UPDATE supermarketcart set qty =".$updateqtyAmt." where sid =".$_POST['id'].";";
      mysql_query($updateQty);
      if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
      $insertGoTo .= (strpos($insertGoTo, '?')) ? "&" : "?";
      $insertGoTo .= $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
  }

      header(sprintf("Location: %s", $insertGoTo));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Before adding an product to the shopping cart you must check if the product is allready in the shopping cart.

Thus, is psuedo code:

```
if product is in shoppincart:
    get the shoppingcart ID
    update record with parameters ProductID and ShoppingcartID, update Count = Count + 1
else:
    // product is not in shopping cart
    perform the insert query.
```

Comment: Hi, I did check whether the product is in the database/shopping cart.
I select all the id and did a check on it.
only first row(first product) is affected for the updating of qty,
while the other row(other product) is not affected.

Comment: take a look at my code, it is somehow similar to what you've mention

Comment: You don't need to receive all the products, only the one you are adding. Thus, you query first SELECT query should be something like: "SELECT ID FROM shoppingcart WHERE ShoppingcartID = X and ProductID = Y". Then you can check if your result ID is NULL or a integer, based on this information you can perform the insert or update query. If you perform the update query you can use the ID from the SELECT query. And you don't need to calculate the qty because MySQL can add one to a cell, just to UPDATE [..] SET qty = qty + 1

Comment: I don't know :P, but i think it has something do with the first code line: "if($fetchSelectedProduct['sid']!= $_POST['id']) {". And what happens above (what i can't see). Although based on what I see now, how does you shoppingcart work with multiple people? What is your primary key in the shoppingcart table?

Comment: the primary key  is basically the id, thus i uses the id to check.

Comment: What you have is one shoppingcart, that will be shared with all the customers on your website. You need a column that can differentiate between customers, further i need code to see what you are really doing. Maybe you can edit your post by adding the part above the if-statement, so I can see what your are doing.

Comment: hmm, I differeniate them by the user, because in order to use the shopping cart, they must log in first

Comment: Ok I see the username you include. I presume you also have a usertable with ID as PK? Better use that ID, but for your question, please extend your question with more code so we can see where it goes wrong.

Comment: hi, 
this is from cart.php, and basically, those are the PHP codes.
it works only for the first row, and not the others

Comment: You select everything, but don't walk through the result to match all product. If you match more than one record you must use a while loop. But your answer is: $selectProduct = "SELECT * FROM supermarketcart WHERE sid = " . $_POST['id'] . " AND username = '" . $_POST['username'] . "';"; IMPORTANT NOTE!!! this query very dangerous, read more on mysql injections and 'parameterized queries'.